# Method of Moment and MLE of Bernoulli

Tags: probability, statistics, maximum-likelihood

Given n observations $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ from a random sample with Bernoulli probability function
$$
\operatorname{Pr}(X=k) = p^k(1-p)^{1-k}, \text{ for }k=0,1.
$$
Denote the method of moment estimator of $p$ as $\tilde{p}$ and the MLE estimator of $p$ as $\hat{p}$

Here is what I got so far.

For MOM,
$$
\operatorname{E}(X) = \mu_{\text{sample}} 
\;\longrightarrow\; \tilde{p} = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}
$$

For MLE,
$$
l(\hat{p};x) 
= \sum_{i=1}^n X_i(\log\hat{p}) 
+ \sum_{i=1}^n (1 - X_i)(\log(1-p)), 
$$
take the derivative and set the equation to zero gave me $\hat{p} = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}$

It seems like the two method gave me the same expression for the estimators; however, I got a hint for this problem as $\tilde{p}$ and $\hat{p}$ are not the same. So I am confused, but unsure about what I did wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you quote the "hint" exactly?  In different cases the MLE and MOM estimators can be the same or different, but here I would expect them to be the same.

Comment: @Henry the hint is simply $\tilde{p}$ is not the same as $\hat{p}$. This is the first part of the question, I was asked to find the unbiasedness of the estimators and MSE of the estimators later. However, I am stuck since if they have the same expression, I just found it was like doing unbiasedness check and MSE twice for the same thing.

Comment: For the problem as you've stated it, your MOM and MLE estimates are correct.  Check carefully that you haven't missed some important detail, but it's possible the problem is simply in error.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr Thank you for helping me to verify my answer. It is possible this is just another error since I have spotted a few already for other questions I got.

Comment: For $p\in [0,1]$, both estimators are same.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Would it change anything if $p\in [0,0.5]$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom I think I see the problem for $p \in [0,0.5]$. For MLE, we have to apply the constraint as $\hat{p}=\min(\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n},0.5)$?